# BC30201 Error SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Good morning,

Using SSRS, I am getting the following error:

> The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox63.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected."

I am using this expression in the

```sql
Textbox: 
=iif(Fields!jhapostingdate.Value>'06/30/2016',(Sum(Fields!CurrentBalance.Value)-117722085)/25000000," ")
```

I'm confused as I believe that the expression is setup correctly.

Any input is highly appreciated!

Comment: You need double quotes around the date.

Comment: I also used `'` before realizing it's `"`... great catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put double quotes around the date.

```
=iif(Fields!jhapostingdate.Value>"06/30/2016",(Sum(Fields!CurrentBalance.Value)-117722085)/25000000," ")
```